Algorithm for Determining Truth of First-Order Sentences in Complex Numbers
Following my previous question Decidability in Natural Numbers with a Combined Function, I realized that there is a spectrum regarding the hardness of deciding whether a first-order sentence is true in structures $(\mathbb{N}, +, \cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$. To understand this spectrum better, I came across this question: Tarski's Decidability Proof on Real Closed Field and Peano Arithmetic.
When Kaveh mentioned, and I quote:

"Another example: consider complex numbers. Their theory ACF is kind of even simpler than real numbers."

I tried to understand why $(\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ has an algorithm for determining whether a first-order sentence is true in this structure. I thought we could represent each complex number by the pair $(a, b)$, where $a$ is the real part and $b$ is the imaginary part. However, using the algorithm which decides whether a first-order sentence is true in the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ is not clear to me because we are now quantifying over pairs. Shouldn't there be additional complexity since the elements are now complex numbers?
My concrete question is: Why, considering that there is an algorithm deciding whether a given first-order sentence is true in the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ (by Tarski's theorem), do we conclude that there is a similar algorithm for complex numbers with the same signature?

It's simpler because polynomials are easy to solve over $\mathbb{C}$. So for example existential statements of the form "does this polynomial have a root?" are always true. Note also that there's no way to define an ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ from this algebraic structure, unlike for $\mathbb{R}$. I've been told that quantifier elimination for this theory is related to (equivalent to?) Chevalley's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_set_(topology)

There are two very important results at play here, which give two different ways to understand decidability of the complex field.
First, as you hinted at in your question, there is an interpretation of the complex field in the real field. This means not just that we can represent every complex number as a pair of real numbers, but also that the field operations on $\mathbb{C}$ are definable functions over $\mathbb{R}$.
For example, the product of the complex  numbers represented by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is the complex number represented by $(ac-bd,ad+bc)$. Using this interpretation, given any sentence $\varphi$ in the language of rings, we can produce another sentence $\varphi'$ in the language of rings such that $\mathbb{C}\models \varphi$ if and only if $\mathbb{R}\models \varphi'$. The idea in this case is to replace each variable by two variables (for the real and imaginary parts), replace each quantifier by two quantifiers of the same type, and translate each atomic formula (equation) to the conjunction of a pair of equations (for the real and imaginary parts).
We can then use the decision algorithm for $\mathbb{R}$ on $\varphi'$ to decide the truth of $\varphi$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
But perhaps more fundamentally, the complex field has a "native" decision algorithm that doesn't rely on decidability of the real numbers. Indeed, the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ admits quantifier elimination (constructively), so for every quantifier-free sentence about $\mathbb{C}$, we can produce an equivalent quantifier-free sentence, and it is easy to determine the truth of quantifier-free sentences in the language of rings.
In fact, the decidability of $\mathbb{C}$ is considerably easier to prove than the corresponding result for $\mathbb{R}$. And from the point of view of model theory, the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ is tamer than the theory of real closed fields (e.g., the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ has a unique model up to isomorphism of each uncountable cardinality, while the theory of real closed fields has $2^\kappa$-many model of cardinality $\kappa$ for all $\kappa$).
